# 2 profiles, 2 method implementations, 1 call in html file via Thymeleaf. How?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-profiles

I had just 1 implementation in my app that was using a certain class and its methods. I have added another implementation and turned on profiles. Adding a second profile made me implement that class for each profile separately, as there were some differences.

The problem is, that before the change I had that specific method invoked through `Thymeleaf` in html file as follows:

```
<td class="text-center" id="hashrate" th:text="${@findAndDisplayDataService.formatHashrate(networkHashrate.hashrate)}">Sample hashrate</td>
```

Now the name of the class has changed to:
`FindAndDisplayDataServiceQuartz` and `FindAndDisplayDataServiceSpringScheduler` accordingly to profiles. I'm not longer able to call the method in html file. I have wrapped both classes with an interface `FindAndDisplayDataService`, but I'm not really able to call interface method in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `FindAndDisplayDataServiceQuartz` and `FindAndDisplayDataServiceSpringScheduler` implement a common `interface`, possibly with same `bean` qualifier so you can autowire without worrying about bean names. Something like the below would do.

Define a common interface.

```
    public interface FindAndDisplayDataService {
       void formatHashrate(String hashrate);
    }
```

Create profile specific bean definitions that extend the common interface.

```
   @Component("findAndDisplayDataService")
   @Profile("quartz")
   public FindAndDisplayDataServiceQuartz implements FindAndDisplayDataService {
      public void formatHashrate(String hashrate){
        //do stuff based on quartz
      }
   }

   @Component("findAndDisplayDataService")
   @Profile("spring-scheduler")
   public FindAndDisplayDataServiceSpringScheduler implements FindAndDisplayDataService {
      public void formatHashrate(String hashrate){
        //do stuff based on Spring scheduler
      }
   }
```

And in your `thymeleaf` template, You can inject any bean based on the `@Component` name `findAndDisplayDataService`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `UIService` as a delegate, where you inject your `FindAndDisplayDataService` interface. That way you can call a concrete bean reference.